# Django says that table doesn't exist while it does

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, uwsgi

My ultimate goal is to deploy Django application on new server and all I have is raw image of disk of the old server. I have everything set up on the new server: uwsgi, python, mysql, django etc. But let's get to my problem: when I run

```
uwsgi --http :8001 --module propotolki.wsgi
```

It runs without errors but when I try to access it through browser I get the following stack trace in the logs:

```
Internal Server Error: / 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 90, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request)
  File "./apps/middleware/middleware.py", line 11, in process_request
    if RedirectHandler.objects.filter(is_active=True, redirect_from=request.path).exists():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 512, in exists
    return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 409, in has_results
    return bool(compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 781, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 124, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'propotolki.middleware_redirecthandler' doesn't exist")
```

Here's what I get from mysql console, proving that the table *does* exist:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| propotolki         |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> use propotolki;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+---------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_propotolki                  |
+---------------------------------------+
| auth_group                            |
| auth_group_permissions                |
| auth_permission                       |
| auth_user                             |
| auth_user_groups                      |
| auth_user_user_permissions            |
| bla_files_blafile                     |
| bla_files_sitefiles                   |
| calc_anglealum                        |
| calc_anglesteelwhite                  |
| calc_baseheight                       |
| calc_cellsize                         |
| calc_color                            |
| calc_outgo_bc_25                      |
| calc_pendant                          |
| calc_price                            |
| calc_roofcolor                        |
| calc_size                             |
| catalog_brand                         |
| catalog_category                      |
| catalog_colortemperature              |
| catalog_diffuser                      |
| catalog_floortype                     |
| catalog_lightoutput                   |
| catalog_order                         |
| catalog_orderinfo                     |
| catalog_product                       |
| catalog_product_categories            |
| catalog_product_color_temperature     |
| catalog_product_diffuser              |
| catalog_product_floor_type            |
| catalog_product_light_output          |
| catalog_product_related               |
| catalog_product_related_categories    |
| catalog_productsliderimage            |
| catalog_sessionbasket                 |
| chunks_chunk                          |
| chunks_group                          |
| chunks_image                          |
| chunks_media                          |
| django_admin_log                      |
| django_content_type                   |
| django_ipgeobase_ipgeobase            |
| django_ipgeobase_ipgeobase_city       |
| django_ipgeobase_ipgeobase_country    |
| django_ipgeobase_ipgeobase_region     |
| django_session                        |
| django_site                           |
| feedback_feedback                     |
| gallery_gallerygroup                  |
| gallery_galleryimage                  |
| left_menu_leftmenuitem                |
| middleware_breadcrumbs                |
| middleware_flatpages                  |
| middleware_redirecthandler            |
| middleware_slidebar                   |
| propotolki.django_content_type        |
| propotolki.middleware_redirecthandler |
| south_migrationhistory                |
| thumbnail_kvstore                     |
| watson_searchentry                    |
+---------------------------------------+
61 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I am far from being Django expert, so please ask for any needed info.
I also tried doing `python manager.py syncdb` but I get similar error telling that other tables also doesn't exist:

```
# python manage.py syncdb
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 92, in handle_noargs
    syncdb.Command().execute(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 112, in handle_noargs
    emit_post_sync_signal(created_models, verbosity, interactive, db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 216, in emit_post_sync_signal
    interactive=interactive, db=db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 185, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 82, in create_permissions
    ctype = ContentType.objects.db_manager(db).get_for_model(klass)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 47, in get_for_model
    defaults = {'name': smart_text(opts.verbose_name_raw)},
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 154, in get_or_create
    return self.get_queryset().get_or_create(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 373, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**lookup), False
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 301, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 77, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 854, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 220, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 710, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 781, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 124, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'propotolki.django_content_type' doesn't exist")
```

Answer (score 1):

How did your table names end up with a '.' in them? It's a special character.

```
| propotolki.django_content_type        |
| propotolki.middleware_redirecthandler |
```

Try:

```
ALTER TABLE `propotolki.middleware_redirecthandler` RENAME TO middleware_redirecthandler
```

You will need to do the same for the `django_content_type` table too.

Comment: I wonder that too, but I already have tables named `middleware_redirecthandler` and `django_content_type`...

Comment: I bet those tables also have spaces or other special characters in them. Itf that is right, the above rename table will fail. Oh rather you would not be able to select or do anything on middleware_redirecthandler without wrapping it in backticks

Comment: yep, the above rename fails: `ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table 'middleware_redirecthandler' already exists`. But when I try select anything from that table (I copied the name from terminal in case of special characters) I am told that the table doesn't exist.

Comment: Rename it to something and rename it back. Also try repair table.

Comment: I get this: `alter table \`middleware_redirecthandler\` rename to \`mr\`;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'propotolki.middleware_redirecthandler' doesn't exist`; Also can't repair it because it says that the tables doesn't exist

Comment: Might it be because of the way I copied database from disk image? I just copied the files from /var/lib/mysql folder.

Comment: Raw copy is not always the best way to do it, but if this is all that you have. The next thing to try is to create a dump (mysqldump) then edit the table name in the dump file manually

Comment: still doesn't work...`mysqldump: Got error: 1146: Table 'propotolki.auth_group' doesn't exist when using LOCK TABLES`. Is there any "proper" way to restore database when all I have is just disk image?

Comment: Post a new question. Leave out all the django parts and the other tables. Mention all the things you have tried in this discussion and others.

Comment: turned out the problem is that the image was made while mysql server was still running which resulted in corrupted database copy. Thanks for taking time anyway, I'm gonna try to find a way to get new copies...